# Half of me exist, rid-dle

Tags: riddle

> My brother never sees me
>
> But sometimes, we share a crown
>
> I'm usually black, white or yellow
>
> If you cut me in half, I can actually be

**hint 1:**

> I am a legendary creature

**hint 2:**

> I often appear in flags

Comment: Any other hint? Or that's it?  if any answer is not correct then add some hints..

Comment: Sure I can add a hint (should be more easy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> a [double-headed eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-headed_eagle)

My brother never sees me

> The heads look in opposite directions

But sometimes, we share a crown

> There's sometimes a single crown above the two heads

I'm usually black, white or yellow

> For example, black in the Albanian flag, yellow in the Montenegrin flag, white in Serbia's coat of arms.

If you cut me in half, I can actually be

> One-headed eagles exist.

Comment: Maybe hint 2 was a bit *too* easy :p

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> The moon

My brother never sees me

> The sun and the moon can rarely be seen together.

But sometimes, we share a crown

> During a solar eclipse, that is.

I'm usually black, white or yellow

> It's black in an eclipse, and white or sometimes yellow at night.

If you cut me in half, I can actually be

> Sometimes a "half moon" can be seen.

Comment: Nice try ! Not the answer tho

Answer (score 2):

It could be,

> Janus, a two faced Roman god.

```
My brother never sees me
```

> The faces are opposite of each other, so he can't see the other face.
>  Or, that one is facing the past and the other is facing the future.

```
But sometimes, we share a crown
```

> They often are depicted with a single crown.

```
I'm usually black, white or yellow
```

> Since he is a god, he is motsly represented in black ink, white statues or yellow(ish) coins.

```
If you cut me in half, I can actually be
```

> Something to do with separating the 2 faces?

Comment: You are on the right way, not right answer tho !

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> A tooth

As,

About brother and being seen

> The inner tooth and exterior tooth cannot see each other

About a crown

> A tooth can be capped with a crown(for support/cosmetic purposes)

Colors

> It can be in black/white/yellow colours

Cutting

> A tooth can be cut into half, still it would be a tooth

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> A bean?

Because

> I don't know for the 1st and 2nd tips but there is black beans, white beans and yellow beans and "bean" cut in half is just "be".

Comment: orre jbhyq nyfb svg

Comment: a bean with a crown ! Nice try

Answer (score 0):

well according to me the answer is

> A night/knight.

My brother never sees me

> a day never sees a night and vice versa.

But sometimes, we share a crown

> but only sometimes that is in dawn and dusk when they are together for a while and share a crown i.e. when they share time.

I'm usually black, white or yellow

> a night is  usually black when there is no moon or stars visible, kind of white when the sky is full of stars.

If you cut me in half, I can actually be

> not sure about this one.

hint

> a knight is a legendary creature.

Answer (score 0):

It is...

> unicorn

My brother never sees me

> Horse and unicorn are seems like brothers, but horse nevers sees unicorn

But sometimes, we share a crown

> unicorn have one horn(as a crown here) on head

I'm usually black, white or yellow

> Usually it's seems in black and white colors

If you cut me in half, I can actually be

> If you cut unicorn from middle , half part will look like horse, and horses are actually exist and unicorns are just imaginary creature as per your hint

Hint:

I am a legendary creature

> Yes, It is legendary creature, found in fairy tails etc..

Comment: Nice try, not an unicorn tho !

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

> Eyes

My brother never sees me

> one eye can not see another eye

But sometimes, we share a crown

> Both share same glasses or sects.

I'm usually black, white or yellow

> eye color are black and white

If you cut me in half, I can actually be

> Not sure about it

For Hint

> May be its related to "Cyclops"

Comment: what about the hint ??

Comment: Updated Answer..

Comment: he's much a comical creature rather than legendary.?

Answer (score 0):

It is...

> Cerberus

My brother never sees me

> He is always on the underground to prevent the dead from leaving

But sometimes, we share a crown

> People often confuse Cerberus with his brother Orthrus

I'm usually black, white or yellow

> He is usually painted in those colors in antiques

If you cut me in half, I can actually be

> If you cut one of his heads he can look like his brother (with 2 heads)